# What types of surface materials can be used for the transition between paved and unpaved surfaces on a runway?

Tags: faa

I wasn't able to find much about it on FAA. Can anyone guide me? I've seen some airports using gravel but isn't it dangerous for aircraft? how can they elliminate the FOD danger?